# Create a dictionary in c# which is strongly coupled with another dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am working with C# for a Hexagon shaped grid with bound checks and wrapping etc. The map in the library is a dictionary `Dictionary<TileCoord,int> tileIndexByPosition`. I also have the required function to obtain `CornerCoord` for each tile.

I would like to create a dictionary `Dictionary<CornerCoord,int> cornerIndexByPosition` whose values depend on `tileIndexByPosition`. Whenever `tileIndexByPosition` changes its elements creating a new dictionary for corners seems quite inefficient.

The idea I have is to use the Lazy evaluation of LINQ to strongly couple the two dictionary. Would like any advice on how to approach this problem.

EDIT: I use these dictionary to check if a `TileCoord` or `CornerCoord` is part of the map by using the `ContainsKey`.

Comment: Create a class and store the int there, then use that instead of the int as Value. If both dictioaries contain the same references it should work

Comment: I would like to be able to check if a particular coordinate exists in map by doing contains key on the dictionary.

Comment: Maybe create a class which holds the required information and offers dictionaries as public properties and methods to set a new point. Internally, you can store the information as you would like, you only need to make sure that they are both updated through the method.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a KeyValuePair like this

```
KeyValuePair<Dictionary<TileCoord,int>,Dictionary<CornerCoord,int>> kvp;
```

If you change the Key ( tileIndexByPosition ) you also can change the Dictonary Value of the KeyValuePair Value that depends on the KeyValuePair Key.

This is like you said you want. But I think you want something like this:

```
Dictonary<KeyValuePair<TileCoord,int>,KeyValuePair<CornerCoord,int>> dic;
```

I hope this helps.

Kind regards

Comment: Does this mean changes to the `tileIndexDictionary` have to be done through this key value pair?

Comment: You need to get the Pair of the dictonary and then change the Pair of the dictonary. If you want to change `tileIndexDictonary` in my first solution it can be done like this: `kvp.Key[index] = //SomethingNew;` In my secon like this: `dic[index].Key = //SomethingNew;`